# TextView from string programmatically?

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView and String passed using Intents.
How to make TextView to set text from passed string?

```
final  String RNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME").trim();

TextView txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtz);
    txt.setText(String.valueOf("RNAME"));
```

I also tried with:

```
txt.setText(RNAME);
```

But it doesn't work. It's showing RNAME instead of string text
Also:

```
   txt.setText(toString(RNAME));
```

But I get error RNAME cannot be resolved to a variable

My textView

```
 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtz"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:text=""
          android:textSize="35sp"
          android:textColor="#FFFF00"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Why are you using `final` for that String variable  ?

Comment: `final` modifier is not needed.

Comment: I need it for something else. Unrelated to TextView

Comment: i think you should accept the answer which was given first!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String RNAME = String.valuOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME").trim());

TextView txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtz);
txt.setText("RNAME");
```

Make sure that the intent extras and getStringExtra are null or not.

Comment: remove quotes from `"RNAME"`

Comment: Actually the problem was I put textView above final Strings, I just moved it under and it worked.

Comment: @user3094736 next time post your question with enough details. You din't mention that textview was before the string initialized

Comment: Yeah I am sorry I didn't realize that. That was bugging me :D

Answer (score 0):

as you are using `txt.setText(String.valueOf("RNAME"));`

do like this please

```
  String RNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME").trim();

TextView txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtz);
    txt.setText(RNAME);
```

Comment: `String RNAME`. So why `String.valueOf(RNAME)`

Comment: anyway on the topic? is edited answer looks good to you!! if yes you can raise it!!

Comment: this wasn't the problem as stated by op under shriram's post. its solved

Answer (score 0):

for sending by intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContent, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
```

for getting and setting textviews text :

```
String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtz);
txt.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember double quotes means the parameter is a string and according you problem you displaying what is inside the quotes not the actual value of a variable 
remove the quotes on RNAME.

```
final  String RNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME").trim();

TextView txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtz);
    txt.setText(String.valueOf(RNAME));
```